Rename a file in Snowflake stage
I have uploaded a local file into snowflake stage with the PUT statement.
Now I need to change the file name, but I couldn't find a way to.
My best attempt so far was to copy the file to the same stage, like this:
COPY FILES INTO @mystage/new_filename FROM @mystage FILES=('current_filename')

But this creates a new file named new_filenamecurrent_filename at @mystage
I would like to avoid having to: (1) download the files, (2) remove the files from stage, (3) rename the downloaded files locally and (4) finally upload them back.
Any other ideas?

Currently, There is no rename functionality on stage files. We can overwrite. it
You could download and rename the file and upload it again or use third-party or cloud provider tools for renaming.
